# finding the real eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix in numpy or scipy

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

I have a real symmetric matrix with a lot of degenerate eigenvalues, and I would like to find the real valued eigenvectors of this matrix. I am struggling to find a method in numpy or scipy that does this for me, the ones I have tried give complex valued eigenvectors. Does anyone know if such a function exists?

Comment: One brute force way is to find all the eigenavlues, then from those store the ones where the imaginary part is zero into a separate array.  I don't think there is a method that finds only the real ones and not the imaginary ones, but could be wrong

Comment: My question is not about finding the real eigenvalues. They are all real. My question is about finding the real eigenvectors.

Comment: For a real symmetric matrix, `eigh` should work.  If it didn't, please show the details in the question, so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think I have made an error. I am using the qutip library (http://qutip.org/), and I called all(isreal()) on the qutip object, which returned true. However when I called all(isreal()) on the full matrix which the qutip object represents, it returned false. This I think was the source of my confusion. I think then that Warren your answer is probably the correct answer to my question.

Comment: Try posting an analytical answer to an example matrix, or a desired result from a given inpu. That is easier to interpret as opposed to one's choice of wording

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.linalg.eigh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) or [`scipy.linalg.eigh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html).  These functions are designed for symmetric (or Hermitian) matrices, and with a real symmetric matrix, they should always return real eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

For example,

```
In [62]: from numpy.linalg import eigh

In [63]: a
Out[63]: 
array([[ 2.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.]])

In [64]: vals, vecs = eigh(a)
```

The eigenvalues are in `vals`, and the corresponding eigenvectors are in the columns of `vecs`:

```
In [65]: vals
Out[65]: array([ 1.,  1.,  3.,  3.])

In [66]: vecs
Out[66]: 
array([[-0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.        , -0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not give me real eigenvectors

Comment: Can you show me an example where it returns complex eigenvectors?

Comment: @JoelKlassen Also, it would be helpful if you included more details of what you have already tried in the question.

Comment: the matrix I am using is a 71 x 71 matrix. I know that it is both real and hermitian. I will try to find a smaller matrix with similar properties.

Comment: Is there some guarantee that the eigh function will return real valued eigenvectors for any real symmetric matrix?

Comment: I just double-checked the source, and it looks like that is the case.  If the input matrix is real, the eigenvectors that `numpy.linalg.eigh` returns are real.

Comment: There was a mistake in how I was using a different library. So my question turned out to be kind of silly and wrong. But this is useful information anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

With a little help from [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
a = np.array([[1, 1j], [-1j, 1]])
w, v = LA.eig(a)
# w are the eigenvalues, v are the eigenvectors
# v.real gives the real-valued parts of the eigenvectors
# v == v.real gives a boolean mask for where the vector equals its own real part
real_eigenvectors = v[v.real == v]
```

Comment: The eig function returns a set of eigenvectors which are not unique to the matrix under consideration. This is because the matrix is degenerate. Your proposal does not find a complete set of real eigenvectors for the matrix under consideration, it simply takes the arbitrary set of complex eigenvectors which eig has returned, and selects any that happen to be real. This is not what I have in mind.

Comment: Ah. Then I think your question needs clarification. Saying you want "the real-valued eigenvectors" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

```
vals, vecs = eigh(a)
vals = vals.real
vecs = vecs.real
```

should work.